# Nextjs Build Error: Export encountered errors on following paths /users/[userid]

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, netlify, getstaticprops, getstaticpaths

i have created a nextjs app, i'm getting data from an express server deployed on netlify. i have created two pages, the first to display a list of users (i've got the users with getServerSideProps() function) and the second page is when you click on a user, you'll be redirected to the user profile (i've got the user's data with getStaticProps() and getStaticPaths() functions).

**On localhost everything works fine.**

But when i've tried to deploy the app on Netlify, i got this error while building it:

**> Build error occurred 11:24:20 PM: Error: Export encountered errors on following paths /users/[userid]**

The users list file:

```js
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Users({ users }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {users.map((user) => (
        <Link href={`/users/${user._id}`} key={user._id}>
          {user.firstname}
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch("https://***************/api/users");
  const users = await res.json();

  return { props: { users} };
}
```

The profile file:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function singleUser({ user }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello {user.firstname}!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch("https://***************************/api/users");
  const users = await res.json();

  const paths = users.map((user) => ({
    params: { userid: user._id },
  }));

  return { paths, fallback: true };
}

// This also gets called at build time
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await fetch(`https://**********************/api/users/${params.userid}`);
  const user = await res.json();

  return { props: { user: user || {} }, revalidate: 3600 };
}
```

Comment: You can't use `getServerSideProps` when exporting the app as static HTML because the method requires a running server. Try moving the user logic to the client-side code inside your `Users` component.

Comment: still not working!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and what's not working?

Comment: I did this:

`export default function Users() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  const getUsers = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      "http://***********************/api/users"
    );
    const users = await res.json();

    setUsers(users);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {users &&
        users.map((el) => (
          <Link href={`/users/${el._id}`} key={el._id}>
            {el.firstname}
          </Link>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}`

Comment: Please edit your question with this additional code.